# Autofilter method of range class failed - table

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am trying to do this and it runs fine and I got the table filtered based on criteria but It gives me error : Autofilter Method of range class failed.

I am not sure if I am using the correct event to trigger this code:

Here is part of the code the last line is giving the error.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Application.EnableEvents=False

Dim wt As Worksheet
Dim wib As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, frow As Long, ck As Boolean, scol As Long, ecol As Long
Dim manName As String

manName = Me.ComboBox1.Value
Set wt = Sheet3
Set wib = Sheet9   'IB Skills Sheet

wt.Activate
wt.Range("A1") = 2

If Trim(manName) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Manager Selected is Invalid"
    Exit Sub
End If

wib.Activate
wib.Range("C2").Select
wib.AutoFilterMode = False
wib.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    manName
```

I also tried this but I got another error:

```
wib.AutoFilterMode = False
frow = wib.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wib.Range("A1:BH:" & frow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=manName
```

What's interesting is if I put `Debug.Print "Blah Blah..."` just before this I get it printed twice in the Immediate window.

```
wib.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    manName
```

I don't know why it is so ? Maybe I am using wrong event handler here ? Need your assistance. Thank you.

Example:

If I use this :

```
wib.Activate
wib.Range("C2").Select
wib.AutoFilterMode = False
Debug.Print "Bla.."
wib.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    manName
MsgBox "Table Filtered"
```

I get this in the immediate window

> Bla..
>
> Bla..

I never get the Msgbox prompt because the error occurred on the line before it. But when I check the Table on the worksheet it is filtered.

Comment: Put a breackpoit at your Debug.Print statement. When you arrive there first, proceed withF5, next time inspect the stack trace with Ctrl-L. Then you will discover which statement in your Sub truggers the event again

Comment: @DirkHorsten Thanks for the advice I never tried it but I will now. There is nothing that can trigger it again also I  Disabled the Events at 
`Application.EnableEvents=False` so shouldn't it take care of it ?

Comment: Is there any loop?  Because your statements says its printing twice.  I don't see anything wrong in your code.  Instead of using F5 place the cursor inside the code and use F8 to go each lines to identify the error.

Comment: @Sixthsense Thanks I tried it and the control of the program goes to the start again right after it filters the table. Filtering of table triggers the comboBox1_Change Event because it's rowsource property is linked to the Table that's why. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But why doesn't the `Application.EnableEvents=False` prevents it from happening that any suggestions on how can I  avoid this ?

Comment: Worksheet Event is the root cause.  I don't see any enable events false in your code.  Could you please update your code?

Comment: It's there. The second line.

Comment: Hm.. I missed that part.  Everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserForm` controls events are not affected by `Application.EnableEvents` property

so that you must handle them appropriately

should you want to control a single UserForm events you may want to add a module level variable (say, `EnableEvents`) and set it back and forth to `True` or `False` in order to prevent some multiple event firing

for instance

```
Option Explicit

Dim EnableEvents As Boolean '<~~ declare a UserForm scoped variable to account for its event handling
                            '    -> need to add a check in every event handler sub you want to control with it

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    EnableEvents = True '<~~ initialize UserForm event handling variable to True
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim wt As Worksheet
Dim wib As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, frow As Long, ck As Boolean, scol As Long, ecol As Long
Dim manName As String

If EnableEvents = True Then '<~~ let it "fire" the first time

    Application.EnableEvents = False '<~~ this may not be necessary anymore

    manName = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Set wt = Sheet3
    Set wib = Sheet9   'IB Skills Sheet

    wt.Activate
    wt.Range("A1") = 2

    If Trim(manName) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Manager Selected is Invalid"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    wib.Activate
    wib.Range("C2").Select
    wib.AutoFilterMode = False

    EnableEvents = False '<~~ set UserForm event handling variable to False so as not to have this event fired again till next setting it to True
    wib.ListObjects("Tabella1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=manName
    EnableEvents = True '<~~ set UserForm event handling variable back to True to have this event fired normally

    Application.EnableEvents = True ''<~~ this may not be necessary anymore

End If

End Sub
```

---

**edit**: added a *local* event control mode

if you only want to handle a single control specific event you may want to use a `static` variable like follows

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim wt As Worksheet
Dim wib As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, frow As Long, ck As Boolean, scol As Long, ecol As Long
Dim manName As String  

Static ComboBox1_Change As Boolean '<~~ "event-level" variable controlling its triggering

ComboBox1_Change = Not ComboBox1_Change '<~~ toggle the "event-level" variable -> this will have it fire alternatively (you may want to set a different behavior)
If ComboBox1_Change = True Then '<~~ it'll fire alternatively: 1st time YES, 2nd time NO, 3rd time YES...

    ... here goes your code ...     

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot :) I wasn't also aware of the fact the Application.EnableEvents doesn't apply for Userform Events.

Comment: you are welcome. besides this question issue you may clean your code up without any `Activate` nor `Select` statements since they are (almost) always unnecessary